# Must your 3rd party app be signed to integrate with Quickbooks?

Tags: quickbooks

On my development machine (which has the Quickbooks SDK installed) I can connect and interact with QB just fine; the standard workflow of granting access to the external app from w/i QB works.  However, on my production machine I get various and sundry errors:

- Can't start QB.
- Can't start QB because it's already running.
- Can't open more than one company file.

The dev docs lead you to believe that the app must be signed while elsewhere I've found examples where you could run an un-signed example app.  So what is it?  If signing isn't strictly required then any clues as to why I can't get this to work?

**Production Machine**

> QuickBooks Pro 2011 Release R9P (US)
>   Our installed, OOB, Silverlight app

**Dev Machine**

> Quickbooks Premier Contractor Edition 2010 Release R13P (US)
>   Silverlight 4 using COM/C# to connect to QB
>   Quickbooks SDK 11.0

As I've said, the dev machine works as it should.  On the production machine we've tried every combo of not having QB open, having it open but no client file open, having it open and a client file open and we'll get one error or another right at the point we're trying to open a connection.  Also, our app never shows up in the integrated applications settings page (but it does show up on the dev machine's QB).  We've tried both admin and non admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Silverlight app with full trust.  It looks as though it was something with SL itself.  Once we upgraded to SL5 it worked fine.

Comment: Let me know how you used Quick Book dlls in silverlight. Can you look at this linke..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495110/how-do-i-add-reference-quick-books-dll-to-silverlight-project

Answer (score 2):

No, you DO NOT need to sign your apps.

You didn't provide anywhere near enough information for us to really give you a solution.

- Did you check your SDK logs?
- What version/year/edition/country of QuickBooks?
- Are you building for the Web Connector, or using C#, or VB .NET, or...?
- If you're using the Web Connector, what do your Web Connector logs look like?
- Are you logged in as the QuickBooks admin user?
- Is QuickBooks already running?
- Is there another QuickBooks company file already open?
- Did you revoke permission from the integrated application?

If you expect answers, you have to post some details.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure what details were necessary since I'm just learning to do this.  I will update with the necessary info after I see about these logs.  See?  I didn't even know there were logs to inspect!  Is there any logs I can inspect on the non-dev/non-SDK machine?  As I said, the dev machine works fine.

Comment: Updated the question with details.