# How do i add (reference) Quick book's dll to silverlight project?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbfc

I am using silverlight project.In this i have to use Quick books SDK (QBFC). But problem is silverlight not allowing other assembles.

Because :
   Silverlight uses a different runtime and a subset of the regular .Net framework, which is why we can only reference Silverlight libraries.

So we cannot use  Quick book dlls  as a reference to silver light. But by using web service or RIA service we can solve tha problem.

Let me know is this possible..

if yes how can i do... if not  which approach i have to follow

Answer (score 0):

First, the SL app has to have elevated privileges.  Second, you need to create a COM object with the appropriate ID.  Third, you'll have a dynamic object but you call its methods just like it's a normal class.  Something like this:

```
var qb = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor");
qb.OpenConnection("", "");
// etc.
```